# Unicode comma csv to float?

Tags: python, unicode, floating-point

How do I convert:

```
somelist = [u'10,1', u'2,47', u'1,6']
```

to:

```
somelist = [10.1, 2.47, 1.6]
```

I've tried `replace(",", ".")` with no result.

Answer (score 3):

You'll indeed need to replace the comma:

```
somelist = [float(v.replace(',', '.')) for v in somelist]
```

Demo:

```
>>> somelist = [u'10,1', u'2,47', u'1,6']
>>> [float(v.replace(',', '.')) for v in somelist]
[10.1, 2.47, 1.6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast that string after replacing comma. Something like this:

```
somelist=[float(x.replace(',','.')) for x in somelist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since using a comma as the decimal point character is the convention in many regions of the world, you could use that fact along with the `locale` module to do the conversion:

```
somelist = [u'10,1', u'2,47', u'1,6']

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'french')
somelist = [locale.atof(str(val)) for val in somelist]
print somelist  # -> [10.1, 2.47, 1.6]
```